# Flutter Custom Volume Panel

Tags: android, flutter, android-layout, user-interface, flutter-layout

I have been working on a custom volume panel app for few weeks, I have successfully managed to start accessibility service to listen for volume key events even when the app is closed or terminated now I want to show a slider when volume button is pressed even when the app is terminated I don't know how to do it.Help me if someone knows how to do it. Thanks in advance

Comment: Since the slider will be part of the app's UI, if the app got terminated, you have to restart it again to display the slider. Can you share the purpose of this feature so that people can come up with other better solutions?

Comment: I trying to create an app like volume styles that is available for android.